# Where should one instantiate a global object in Code Igniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to create a global object that represents the current user in Code Igniter. The constructor of the object takes the user id, which is stored in `$_SESSION['user_id']`.

Every time a user visits a page, I want to create this user object. Where should I instantiate it? I think instantiating it in config/constants.php works, but is there a more standard/reliable place to instantiate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to create a `MY_Controller` from which all your other controllers would inherit. The user object could be instantiated within `MY_Controller` and therefore would be available in every controller which inherits from it.

Simplified example:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public $user;

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        // Get the current user (pseudo code, obviously)
        $this->user = $this->user_model->get_user($id);
    }

}

class Some_other_controller extends My_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        // $user is available throughout this controller
    }

}

class Another_controller extends My_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        // $user is available throughout this controller
    }

}
```